# XCode 5 Design Breaks - Navigationbar's height only 4

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode5

I've installed XCode 5 (Developer Preview 3) and opened my old project in it. I see that many View elements are broken and some of them can't be changed. 
1. Navigation's bar is very small - only 4. 
2. Can't change the height of Navigation bar. 
3. Height of some views such as Buttons and Textboxes are decreased.

Please see the screenshot.

[image]

Is there any easy or any way to fix these issues? 
I'm using developer preview 3. Do you think that this is causing the problem?

Comment: Why not upgrading to the final Version of Xcode 5? You can't even sign apps for appstore building with xcode5-d3

Comment: As lukaswelte says. Go to the Mac App Store and upgrade to the final release. If its still a problem you can post your issues, but asking for help with a Preview (Beta) is kinda wrong.

Comment: I tried to install XCode 5. But after some time, it restarts downloading. Any my internet connection is very slow that, it takes 15 hours to download 2 GB.